# Admin access denied with programmatic access in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

I'm an admin user on my AWS account, so I have full access. Working through the console, I get no issues. When I try to work with programmatic access though, I get an access denied error. Does anybody have a clue why?

The code and all is OK, it works fine on my other AWS account on which I have admin access as well. Yes, I did change the AWS configuration to match the access keys to the right account.

Comment: What is the API call you are making? Are you using the awscli, a python boto3 app you wrote, or something else? How are you supplying credentials to it (~/.aws/credentials or environment variables or something else)?

Comment: Please clarify your question with specific details.

Comment: Hi. The API call doesn't matter, it doesn't work with calling basic lists from any service let alone creating a bucket for example. I do this with my other AWS account a lot so I'm sure the code isn't an issue. I'm using awscli, python boto3, the configuration is good. Configuration is applied with aws configure in the cli with access keys and secret access keys.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled MFA in the IAM account. If so, you cannot directly access the AWS CLI or API with Access key. You need to create a temporary Access and secret key and use those to access the AWS resource

With the access key that you configured earlier you need to create the temp access key. Refer the below links for procedure.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mfa-iam-user-aws-cli/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/

Answer (score -1):

If you are 100% sure that your code is correctly assuming your admin role and you admin role is having the admin policy, then you should be facing:

1. The resource(e.g., S3) you are trying to access has some explicit deny policy or not having an allow policy for you user.
2. IAM service latency. Say if you just create this user with admin access and you try to test that immediately with your code, it might happen that AWS thought you don't have enough permission. That happen to me when I created a new role, I saw delay can be up to 20 minutes, but that kind of delay is rare. But you cannot assume your update to IAM permissions to take effect immediately just like the EC2 security group.

Comment: It doesn't work with any calls from any service. I do this with my other AWS account a lot so I'm sure the code isn't an issue. I'm using awscli and python boto3. Configuration is applied with aws configure in the cli with access keys and secret access keys.

I know it's not an IAM issue in itself, there are no explicit denies in my policies and there's no latency issues.

My thoughts are either there is an issue rooting from the permissions given in the root account OR security settings (VPC/subnet/security groups) but I can't figure it out.